# SQL script run history checking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use these script to get the history and get the result as in picture 
I notice that the result of first script is lower than second script 3 rows. 
Actually those missing rows is what I want to check .
Please help me check Why ?

```sql
SELECT t.[text], s.last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
ON p.plan_handle = s.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%update MT_customer%'
ORDER BY s.last_execution_time DESC;
```

[image: result of first script 14 rows]

```sql
SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%update MT_customer%';
```

[image: result of second script 17 rows]

Comment: from the query, It looks like some of your cached plans do not have query stats. hence why the inner join is dropping some of the records.. Just a logical conclusion of course..

Comment: @Harry Can you teach me how to join with out drop any record ? 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s
    ON p.plan_handle = s.plan_handle
Can we join this data with anoter column ?

Comment: an inner join means every record in the table aliased p MUST have a corresponding record in table aliased s. Any that do not match on the plan_handle will be dropped off the selection. turn the inner join to left outer join and you should in theory return 17 rows.

Comment: @harry I see . Thank you very much .